# Neutral value in SELECT mySql query

Tags: mysql, database

I have simple mySql query in my php code:

```
query(sprintf(SELECT * FROM customers WHERE city='%s' AND state='%s' AND age='%s'(...))
```

This query is used in search engine in my application. I want user to be able to search, for example, customers from New York, but for now he must specify 'state' and 'age'.

User can specify search filter by more than one criteria, but doesn't have to specify all of them.

Is there any method that will bypass values not used in current search session?

Answer (score 0):

i believe that you are looking for CASE statement.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html